# cant make login page work

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php page that posts to itself and then it checks weather if to login someone or not. The problem I am having is that if it logins... then it still shows the username and password textboxes.. but if i refresh they go away and now the welcome thing comes up thanks to the session.

What i want is to once the submit is clicked and it logs the person in to immediately not show the textboxes (username, password) and show the welcome message. Right now i have to refresh.

Please note i am new to PHP and any wise advise will be much appreciated.

```
    <?php 

        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"index.php?form_type=$page_vals\">";
        echo "<body>";

        //Start session
         session_start();

       //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
       if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {

         extract($_POST);

       $username = "";
       $password = "";
       $userrole = "";
       $userid ="";

       $login_query = "SELECT user_id, user_role, user_username FROM users WHERE user_username = '$_POST[logInUsername]' AND user_password = '$_POST[logInPassword]'";

        if(!($database = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")))
                die("<p>Could not connect to database</p></div></div>
                                 </body>
                                </html>");

            if(!mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $database))
                die("<p>Could not open my databases database</p></div>
               </div>
                                 </body>
                                </html>");

                if(!($result = mysql_query($login_query, $database)))
                {
                    print("Could not execute query!<br/>");
                    die(mysql_error()."</div>
               </div>            
                                 </body>
                                </html>");
                }


            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
               print("Please verify your login information<br/>");
                }


            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  $username = $row["user_username"];
                  $userrole = $row["user_role"];
                  $userid = $row["user_id"];
              }

            echo "Hello - '$username'";
            mysql_close($database);

            session_regenerate_id();

            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $userid;
            $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $username;

            //Write session to disc
            session_write_close();

                   echo '<div id="login" class="login">
        <label for="login">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="logInUsername" />
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="logInPassword" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
        </div>';
        }
   else 
   {
    $sessionName = $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'];
     echo '<div id="login" class="login">
        <label for="welcome">Welcome '. $sessionName.'!</label>
        </div>';
   }

    ?>
```

Comment: Never use session variables for user authentication.  You can work with page scope, but this is not a recommended practice.

Comment: okay, thank you for the advise.. but how can i solve my problem ignoring that fact. I just want this to work first before i employ best practices. Thank you

Comment: Please either use single quotes (`echo '<div id="foo">';`) or break out of PHP to echo large portions of HTML (`?><div id="foo"><?php`), this is making my eyes bleed. ;-/

Comment: sorry about that <-- i am new to php :) thank you for the advise, how about the issue i am having?

Comment: Well, your logic is simply screwed up. There's no error in the code (apart from it being a terrible way to implement all this and it being open to SQL injection and all), but you're simply outputting the form after logging someone in.

Comment: yes i know.. thank you i am just learning the concept.. and like i said please ignore any bad practices for now.. and help me with the logic which is so screwed up , reason why i came here and pose this question. Thank you

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I'm interested in the reason why one should not use session variables for authentication (I'm guessing session hijacking, but would like to know your reasons) and could you elaborate on what one should be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is just your code is not in sequence. I have corrected Try it now.

```
<?php 
   session_start();

    echo "<body>";

    //Start session
  //print_r($_SESSION);exit;

   //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not

     extract($_POST);

   $username = "";
   $password = "";
   $userrole = "";
   $userid ="";
if(isset($_POST))
{
   $login_query = "SELECT reg_id, role_id, f_name FROM registration WHERE f_name = '$_POST[logInUsername]' AND password = '$_POST[logInPassword]'";

    if(!($database = mysql_connect("sunlinux","pukhraj","pukhraj123")))
            die("<p>Could not connect to database</p></div></div>
                             </body>
                            </html>");

        if(!mysql_select_db("testbaj", $database))
            die("<p>Could not open my databases database</p></div>
           </div>
                             </body>
                            </html>");

            if(!($result = mysql_query($login_query, $database)))
            {
                print("Could not execute query!<br/>");
                die(mysql_error()."</div>
           </div>            
                             </body>
                            </html>");
            }


        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
           print("Please verify your login information<br/>");
            }


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
              $username = $row["f_name"];
              $userrole = $row["role"];
              $userid = $row["reg_id"];
          }

         $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $userid;
        $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $username;
   }
   if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {

        echo "Hello - '$username'";
        mysql_close($database);

        session_regenerate_id();



        //Write session to disc
        session_write_close();

        echo "<form method=\"post\" ><div id=\"login\" class=\"login\">
        <label for=\"login\">User Name</label>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"logInUsername\" />
        <label for=\"Password\">Password</label>
        <input type=\"password\" name=\"logInPassword\" />
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"button\" />
        </div>";
        }
   else 
   {
    $sessionName = $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'];
     echo "<div id=\"login\" class=\"login\">
        <label for=\"welcome\">Welcome '$sessionName' !</label>
        </div>";
   }

?>
```

Small changes :

1. Just plase form tag at appropriate place.
2. Never mix code after post and before post.
3. here all database stuff should be execute after submit so I enclosed them in condition if(isset($_POST))
4. due to nonlinearity of code it was creating session after one more refresh after post data. Now corrected.

for message :

do below changes :

1. give name to submit button  `<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"button\" />`
2. replace first  if condition with `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: Great, how about if I needed to show the "Please verify your log in information only if they attempt (after they click submit) did not logged them in?.. right now that message shows from the beginning..

Comment: have done. do 2 changes according to updated answer(last) for it.

Answer (score 1):

So, not dealing with any of the security or style issues that are here...

Right now you are seeing if the session is set.  If it is not, then you process the login.  After processing the login, you display the form fields.

You should actually check for 3 states...

Is someone already logged in?
Do you need to process a login?
If neither of those, show normal form...

You can do this by using your existing isset for the session field.

Then if it is not set, check if the post fields are set... if they are set, process a login.

Otherwise, show the basic login form.

EDIT:

Full code sample (sorry for the terrible formatting, mostly cut and paste...:

```
 <?php 

        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"index.php?form_type=$page_vals\">";
        echo "<body>";

        //Start session
         session_start();

       //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
       if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) != '')) {
            $sessionName = $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'];
               echo '<div id="login" class="login">
             <label for="welcome">Welcome '. $sessionName.'!</label>
             </div>';

        }
    else if ($_POST[logInPassword] != null && $_POST[logInUsername] != null)
    {
          extract($_POST);

       $username = "";
       $password = "";
       $userrole = "";
       $userid ="";

       $login_query = "SELECT user_id, user_role, user_username FROM users WHERE user_username = '$_POST[logInUsername]' AND user_password = '$_POST[logInPassword]'";

        if(!($database = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")))
                die("<p>Could not connect to database</p></div></div>
                                 </body>
                                </html>");

            if(!mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $database))
                die("<p>Could not open my databases database</p></div>
               </div>
                                 </body>
                                </html>");

                if(!($result = mysql_query($login_query, $database)))
                {
                    print("Could not execute query!<br/>");
                    die(mysql_error()."</div>
               </div>            
                                 </body>
                                </html>");
                }


            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
               print("Please verify your login information<br/>");
                }


            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  $username = $row["user_username"];
                  $userrole = $row["user_role"];
                  $userid = $row["user_id"];
              }

            echo "Hello - '$username'";
            mysql_close($database);

            session_regenerate_id();

            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $userid;
            $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $username;

            //Write session to disc
            session_write_close();

            $sessionName = $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'];
               echo '<div id="login" class="login">
             <label for="welcome">Welcome '. $sessionName.'!</label>
             </div>';


    }
   else 
   {

        echo '<div id="login" class="login">
        <label for="login">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="logInUsername" />
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="logInPassword" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
        </div>';
   }

    ?>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic just needs to be rethought. How about something like this? (pseduocode)

```
if( user is NOT logged in) // Check via session
{
    $errors = array();
    if( user submitted the form and is trying to log in) // Can be checked with a POST'd variable
    {
        // Set the session correctly here, query DB, etc.
        // If there are any errors, add them to the $error array
    }

    if( !empty( $errors) || form was not submitted)
    {
        // Print the form and any errors (like invalid username / password combo)
    }
    exit; // Stop here
}

// Print welcome message here (since we know if we get here, the user is logged in)
```